# R - count how many rows in a data frame have same value and date is within x days

Tags: r

I have a dataframe 'DFrame' that looks like this:

```
RecordNo |  Cust_ID  |  Record_Date
1        |  023      |  2014-03-01
2        |  056      |  2014-01-18
3        |  041      |  2014-03-04
4        |  023      |  2014-03-21
5        |  056      |  2014-01-25
6        |  003      |  2014-03-01
7        |  023      |  2014-04-01
8        |  023      |  2014-04-02
```

I would like to add a column that shows a count of how many times a record by the same customer ID appears in the following 14 days of the current record_date.

```
RecordNo |  Cust_ID  |  Record_Date  | 14-day_Repeat_Count
1        |  023      |  2014-03-01   | 0
2        |  056      |  2014-01-18   | 1
3        |  041      |  2014-03-04   | 0
4        |  023      |  2014-03-21   | 2
5        |  056      |  2014-01-25   | 0
6        |  003      |  2014-03-01   | 0
7        |  023      |  2014-04-01   | 1
8        |  023      |  2014-04-02   | 0
```

I am trying to write fast code in R to accomplish this.  I have found a couple of articles that made counting records that meet conditions look easy, but they generally only point to static conditions or conditions not related to the value of the current record:
http://one-line-it.blogspot.ca/2013/01/r-number-of-rows-matching-condition.html

I imagine the logic may look like:

```
# Sort DFRAME by RECORD_DATE decreasing=FALSE
......
# Count records below current record where that have matching Cust_ID
# AND the Record_Date is <= 14 days of the current Record_Date

# put result into DFrame$14-day_Repeat_Count
......
```

I have done this type of logic in DAX:

```
=calculate(counta([Cust_ID],
      filter(DFrame,
             [Cust_ID]=Earlier([Cust_ID]) &&
             [Record_Date] > Earlier([Record_Date]) &&
             [Record_Date] <= (Earlier([Record_Date]) + 14)
      )
)
```

(very fast but proprietary to Microsoft), and in Excel using 'CountIfs' (easy to implement, very very slow, and again requires marriage to Microsoft), can anyone point me to some reading on how one might count based on criteria in R?

Comment: Is the example data created above correct or just a place holder? The last two rows do not make sense, so its throwing me off. Oh I see you mean following 14 days i.e. 14 days in the future not the previous 14 days.

Comment: That's right, only looking for the count of records that happen AFTER the current record but within 14 days (in the real data the Record_Date is a DateTime value with a full timestamp, so same day records will still have a chronological order).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps a faster, more memory efficient answer might look something like this:

```
##Combine into one data.table
library("data.table")
RecordNo <- 1:36
Record_Date <- c(31,33,38,41,44,59,68,69,75,78,85,88,
                 32,34,45,46,51,54,60,65,67,70,74,80,
                 33,35,42,45,50,60,65,70,75,80,82,85)
Cust_ID <- c(rep(1,12),rep(2,12),rep(3,12))
data <- data.table(Cust_ID,Record_Date)[order(Cust_ID,Record_Date)]

##Assign each customer an number that ranks them
data[,Cust_No:=.GRP,by=c("Cust_ID")]

##Create "list" of comparison dates for each customer
Ref <- data[,list(Compare_Date=list(I(Record_Date))), by=c("Cust_ID")]

##Compare two lists and see of the compare date is within N days
system.time(
  data$Roll.Cnt <- mapply(FUN = function(RD, NUM) {
    d <- as.numeric(Ref$Compare_Date[[NUM]] - RD)
    sum((d > 0 & d <= 14))
  }, RD = data$Record_Date,NUM=data$Cust_No)
)
```

The resulting data looks like the following:

```
data <- data[,list(Cust_ID,Record_Date,Roll.Cnt)][order(Cust_ID,Record_Date)]
data

     Cust_ID   Record_Date  Roll.Cnt
 1:       1          31        4
 2:       1          33        3
 3:       1          38        2
 4:       1          41        1
 5:       1          44        0
 6:       1          59        2
 7:       1          68        3
 8:       1          69        2
 9:       1          75        3
10:       1          78        2
11:       1          85        1
12:       1          88        0
13:       2          32        3
14:       2          34        2
15:       2          45        3
```

Comment: Awesome,  I tried to modify it a bit to take input from a file of test data (~4k records): (csv file here-> http://pastebin.com/a5WRbZW2 )

modified code here-> http://pastebin.com/NajaxL6X <- modified to read from csv file and write output to csv.

but the results are not accurate, most items come back as '0' and a couple of them come back as very high numbers.

Comment: How do you want to handle Cust_IDs that have the same date?  That test data that you provided only has 2 unique date values.  So I think that would explain most of the zeros.  Do you only want to count dates within 14 days that count the same day?

Comment: Hi Mike, in actuality the record_date would actually be a DateTime and includes a full timestamp down to the second the record was entered.  I suppose I over-simplified things thinking I could figure out the details on my own.  Ideally, the repeat_count would be the count of all records that show up within 14 days of the timestamp in Record_Date, IE. if a record were created at '2014-04-16 6:41:20 PM' the 'window' that it is 'hittable' for a repeat record would end (14 days * 24 hours) 336 hours later at '2014=04-30  6:41:20 PM'

Comment: Here's an updated sample where the Record_Date is in it's actual format -> http://pastebin.com/vZCCeCdt
.... And here is a file showing the expected result ->  http://pastebin.com/dFmKLgh0
 ...
(validated using Excel and this formula in column C:C => '=CountIfs(A:A,A:A,B:B,">"&B:B,B:B,"<="&B:B+14)'

Comment: A little bit of debugging, I put a 'head(data)' after you're Create List command, and it shows like this:  http://pastebin.com/0SrwWqD1
When I put the same head(data) in my version of the code that attempts to read the data from a CSV file, it looks like this instead:  http://pastebin.com/GhnCMhWH

Notice how the comparison 'list' created in my version of the code are not dates at all. =/  My full code here: http://pastebin.com/NajaxL6X

Comment: Can you double check your data again?  For example, customer ids 226896,284200,295663, plus about 110 more don't match my numbers.  Do you think something went wrong with the sorting?  I don't want to imply my answer is more right than yours, I just am getting results that seem to be consistent with what the problem wants (at least from my side of things)

Comment: Those are just dates converted to numbers.  What version of R are you running?  I noticed a possible bug in data.table for the newer verison of R. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23120781/need-help-understanding-r-data-table-behavior?noredirect=1#comment35347136_23120781

Comment: I just made a slight edit to the code that should allow the code to work (even with the latest version of R)                                                  http://pastebin.com/vxasxKkf

Comment: Wow!  It seems to work, and it's like 100x faster than Excel.  I tried to take a peak at why the results were different, so I added code to 'keep' the 'old datetime' before they get re-cast as numeric values.. (see my slight changes to your code here> http://pastebin.com/LdB45ZA3) I found a couple parts where the difference might be explained by some strangeness when re-casting the dates into number values: http://pastebin.com/e0ddRavU  IE shouldn't the later time (7:25:10 PM) be a larger decimal number than the earlier time (8:17:05 AM)? Perhaps my code to keep the original datetime is wrong?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50836/discussion-between-timonippon-and-mike-gahan

Answer (score 3):

To make this easier, I created some more realistic sample data to re-create your problem.

```
##Make some sample variables
Record_Date <- as.Date(c(31,33,38,41,44,59,68,69,75,78,85,88,
                         32,34,45,46,51,54,60,65,67,70,74,80,
                         33,35,42,45,50,60,65,70,75,80,82,85),origin="2010-01-01")
Cust_ID <- c(rep(1,12),rep(2,12),rep(3,12))

##Combine into one data.table
library("data.table")
data <- data.table(Cust_ID,Record_Date)

   Cust_ID Record_Date
 1:       1  2010-02-01
 2:       1  2010-02-03
 3:       1  2010-02-08
 4:       1  2010-02-11
 5:       1  2010-02-14
 6:       1  2010-03-01
 7:       1  2010-03-10
 8:       1  2010-03-11
 9:       1  2010-03-17
10:       1  2010-03-20
11:       1  2010-03-27
12:       1  2010-03-30
13:       2  2010-02-02
14:       2  2010-02-04
15:       2  2010-02-15
16:       2  2010-02-16
17:       2  2010-02-21
```

I am not sure there is a very efficient way in R to do what you want to do, but I think that going with the data.table package might be a good bet.

```
output <- data[,as.list(data[,list(Cust_ID2=Cust_ID,Compare_Date=Record_Date)]),
  by=c("Cust_ID","Record_Date")][Cust_ID==Cust_ID2 & Compare_Date>=Record_Date,list(Cust_ID,Record_Date,Compare_Date,
    Within14=(as.numeric(Compare_Date-Record_Date)<=14)*1)][,list(Within14=(sum(Within14)-1)),by=c("Cust_ID","Record_Date")]   

    Cust_ID Record_Date Within14
 1:       1  2010-02-01        4
 2:       1  2010-02-03        3
 3:       1  2010-02-08        2
 4:       1  2010-02-11        1
 5:       1  2010-02-14        0
 6:       1  2010-03-01        2
 7:       1  2010-03-10        3
 8:       1  2010-03-11        2
 9:       1  2010-03-17        3
10:       1  2010-03-20        2
11:       1  2010-03-27        1
12:       1  2010-03-30        0
13:       2  2010-02-02        3
14:       2  2010-02-04        2
15:       2  2010-02-15        3
16:       2  2010-02-16        3
17:       2  2010-02-21        3
```

For your specific data, the output would look like this:

```
##Combine into one data.table
Record_Date <- as.Date(c("2014-03-01","2014-01-18","2014-03-04","2014-03-21","2014-01-25","2014-03-01",
                       "2014-04-01","2014-04-02"))
Cust_ID <- c("023","056","041","023","056","003","023","023")


data <- data.table(Cust_ID,Record_Date)

output <- data[,as.list(data[,list(Cust_ID2=Cust_ID,Compare_Date=Record_Date)]),
  by=c("Cust_ID","Record_Date")][Cust_ID==Cust_ID2 & Compare_Date>=Record_Date,list(Cust_ID,Record_Date,Compare_Date,
    Within14=(as.numeric(Compare_Date-Record_Date)<=14)*1)][,list(Within14=(sum(Within14)-1)),by=c("Cust_ID","Record_Date")]      

output

Cust_ID Record_Date Within14
1:     023  2014-03-01        0
2:     056  2014-01-18        1
3:     041  2014-03-04        0
4:     023  2014-03-21        2
5:     056  2014-01-25        0
6:     003  2014-03-01        0
7:     023  2014-04-01        1
8:     023  2014-04-02        0
```

Comment: Amazingly helpful and seems really fast.  I'm somehow running into a couple of problems with memory allocation problems once I bump the data size up to just 15k records (which is a drop in the bucket in terms of data sets I work with):

Error: cannot allocate vector of size 3.4 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In `[.data.table`(data, , as.list(data[, list(Cust_ID2 = Cust_ID,  :
  Reached total allocation of 8089Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In `[.data.table`(data, , as.list(data[, list(Cust_ID2 = Cust_ID,  :
  Reached total allocation of 8089Mb: see help(memory.size)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you'll get much faster than Rcpp.

First, sort the data frame.

```
df = read.table(text="RecordNo   Cust_ID    Record_Date
1          023        2014-03-01
2          056        2014-01-18
3          041        2014-03-04
4          023        2014-03-21
5          056        2014-01-25
6          003        2014-03-01
7          023        2014-04-01
8          023        2014-04-02",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df$Record_Date = as.Date(df$Record_Date)
df$Record_Date = as.numeric(df$Record_Date - min(df$Record_Date))
df = df[order(df$Record_Date),]
```

Then calculate the counts with an Rcpp function.

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('
  NumericVector count_14( NumericVector id, NumericVector day) {
            unsigned int n=id.size(), i, j;
            NumericVector out(n);

            for( i=0; i<n; i++ ) {
              j=1;
              while( day[i+j] - day[i] <= 14 && i+j<n )
                if( id[i]==id[i+j++] ) out[i]++;
            }
            return out;
            }')
df$count = count_14(df$Cust_ID,df$Record_Date)
df[order(df$RecordNo),]
#   RecordNo Cust_ID Record_Date count
# 1        1      23          42     0
# 2        2      56           0     1
# 3        3      41          45     0
# 4        4      23          62     2
# 5        5      56           7     0
# 6        6       3          42     0
# 7        7      23          73     1
# 8        8      23          74     0
```

Comment: At this point I can read C code much better than I can read R code, so I'm not scared away by this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use `findInterval()` that has O(n*log n) complexity:

```
DF <- read.csv(text=
'"RecordNo","Cust_ID","Record_Date"
1,"023","2014-03-01"
2,"056","2014-01-18"
3,"041","2014-03-04"
4,"023","2014-03-21"
5,"056","2014-01-25"
6,"003","2014-03-01"
7,"023","2014-04-01"
8,"023","2014-04-02"',
stringsAsFactors=F)

DF$Record_Date <- as.POSIXct(DF$Record_Date,format='%Y-%m-%d',tz='GMT')

# sort by ascending date
DF <- DF[order(DF$Record_Date),]

# for each date D we find the row index of the first next date <= D+14
DF$EndIdx <- findInterval(x=DF$Record_Date+14*60*60*24,vec=DF$Record_Date)

DF$Count <- 
sapply(1:nrow(DF), FUN=function(i){
                          currRow <- DF[i,]
                          sum(DF[i:currRow$EndIdx,'Cust_ID'] == currRow$Cust_ID)
                       })

> DF
  RecordNo Cust_ID Record_Date EndIdx Count
2        2      56  2014-01-18      2     2
5        5      56  2014-01-25      2     1
1        1      23  2014-03-01      5     1
6        6       3  2014-03-01      5     1
3        3      41  2014-03-04      5     1
4        4      23  2014-03-21      8     3
7        7      23  2014-04-01      8     2
8        8      23  2014-04-02      8     1
```

Comment: This seems the fastest so far, I've actually made it a little faster by changing the EndIdx to point to the next row where the Cust_ID changes after sorting by Cust_ID (there are millions of customers, but much fewer dates, so it makes more much smaller loop sizes if only having to look at potentially 2-5 records that belong to a given customer rather than tens or hundreds of thousands of records between dates.)    I'm now wondering if it would be possible to make even faster by replacing the sapply with ddply or something else that supports parallelism.  Can't seem to get dpply working though

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a fast way to do this, but it should give someone a start. In my experience, rolling calculations in R can be difficult to make fast. If you can't find a clever solution, you might have to take a look at `Rcpp`.

```
df = read.table(text="RecordNo   Cust_ID    Record_Date
1          023        2014-03-01
2          056        2014-01-18
3          041        2014-03-04
4          023        2014-03-21
5          056        2014-01-25
6          003        2014-03-01
7          023        2014-04-01
8          023        2014-04-02",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# I don't like working with dates
# Converting to number of days after earliest day
df$Record_Date = as.Date(df$Record_Date)
df$Record_Date = as.numeric(df$Record_Date - min(df$Record_Date))

# Use a slow loop to do the calculations
for( i in 1:nrow(df) ) {
  window = df$Record_Date < df$Record_Date[i] + 14 & 
               df$Record_Date > df$Record_Date[i]
  df$count[i] = sum(df$Cust_ID[window] == df$Cust_ID[i])
}

df
#   RecordNo Cust_ID Record_Date count
# 1        1      23          42     0
# 2        2      56           0     1
# 3        3      41          45     0
# 4        4      23          62     2
# 5        5      56           7     0
# 6        6       3          42     0
# 7        7      23          73     1
# 8        8      23          74     0
```

Comment: Hmm, well this is simple, but definitely not fast.  Since there is nothing inside the loop dependent on any previous iteration of the loop being complete, etc. could this not be made parallel or vectorized quite easily?  For example, using one of the 'apply()' functions or such?

Comment: I can't think of any easy way to do parallelization or vectorization. The bottleneck is finding the 14 dat interval from the entire vector of dates. In another language, you could more easily search subsets of the vector and save gobs of time. I can't think of any other way to find this interval in R without searching the entire vector for every row. I don't think the apply functions will help you here. Hopefully someone proves me wrong.