# Need Help Understanding r data.table Behavior

Tags: r, data.table

I am having a little trouble understanding the behavior of the following in data.table...

```
##Combine into one data.table
RecordNo <- 1:36
Record_Date <- c(31,33,38,41,44,59,68,69,75,78,85,88,
                         32,34,45,46,51,54,60,65,67,70,74,80,
                         33,35,42,45,50,60,65,70,75,80,82,85)
Cust_ID <- c(rep(1,12),rep(2,12),rep(3,12))
data <- data.table(RecordNo,Record_Date,Cust_ID)

##Create "list" of comparison dates
data[,list(Compare_Date=list(Record_Date)),by=c("Cust_ID")]

   Cust_ID       Compare_Date
1:       1 33,35,42,45,50,60,
2:       2 33,35,42,45,50,60,
3:       3 33,35,42,45,50,60,
```

The above code outputs the date list for Cust_ID=3 for each Cust_ID.  I desire an output like this..

```
   Cust_ID       Compare_Date
1:       1 31,33,38,41,44,59,
2:       2 32,34,45,46,51,54,
3:       3 33,35,42,45,50,60,
```

Any ideas why data.table is returning the list of dates for Cust_ID 3 instead of the correct list of values for each Cust_ID?

```
sessionInfo()

R version 3.1.0 beta (2014-03-28 r65330)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.9.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] plyr_1.8.1     Rcpp_0.11.0    reshape2_1.2.2 stringr_0.6.2  tools_3.1.0
```

Comment: I get your desired output.  You might want to clear your workspace and copy/paste your reproducible code to see if you get the same problem.

Comment: same here, running dt 1.9.3

Comment: Very strange.  It is still actiing up.  Maybe I will try uninstalling and then reinstalling data.table.

Comment: Are you running R v3.1.0? Then this is a [new bug](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=5585&group_id=240&atid=975) yet to be fixed. Use the fix under [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993637/efficient-r-code-for-finding-indices-associated-with-unique-values-in-vector/22994546#comment35130204_22994546) for now.

Comment: Sorry...I am still a little bit of a newbie.  How do I mark "fix" under this comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** The behaviour `DT[, list(list(.)), by=.]` sometimes resulted in wrong results in R version >= 3.1.0. This is now fixed in [commit #1280](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/86276f48798491d328caa72f6ebcce4d51649440) in the current development version of [data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table) v1.9.3. From [NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/README.md):

> - `DT[, list(list(.)), by=.]` returns correct results in R >=3.1.0 as well. The bug was due to recent (welcoming) changes in R v3.1.0 where `list(.)` does not result in a *copy*. Closes [#481](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/481).

With this fix, there's no need for the `I()` anymore.

---

Seems to work if I put in an "I" before the list:

```
##Create "list" of comparison dates
data[,list(Compare_Date=list(I(Record_Date))),by=c("Cust_ID")]
```